# What does transactions per seconds for a load balancer mean

Tags: networking, load-balancing

I was looking at the product matrix of webmux 592G(load balancer).
It says
maximum connections per sec = 2.8M
Maximum number of transactions  = 100,000

What does the above numbers mean.
Does above means that load balancer can have 2.8M connections open but only 100K of them will be active per seconds.

Also incase any one has used webmux 592G do you guys know in practice how many connections it can have open and what qps it can serve

Comment: A noticeable point is:Maximum number of transactions is not be counted by second (assume). I think, transaction here is more stabile, logical (may be 1 level higger in OSI), long lifetime than connection. A transaction could use (or be asssociated with more than one connection. And this question should be posted on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Here's an idea, why not call them and ask? http://www.redhillnetworks.com/company/contacts.htm

Comment: Cisco has a similar metric on their load balancer, and they were not able to define a transaction for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell. **You need to contact the manufacturer and ask.**

With load balancers it's common to specify [L4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_4) and L7 (TCP/IP and HTTP) separately. Since the load balancer does less work if it load balances on L4, the L4 rate will generally be a great deal higher. But that doesn't quite seem to be the case here, since "transactions" isn't really a common word for L7.

Another approach is to discern on max rate with larger payloads (say 50 - 100 kb), and with small payloads (4 - 8 kb). Again, this doesn't quite match the words used in this case, so you should contact the manufacturer for clarification.